# SimpleModal + UI Layout: block out div instead of body

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, simplemodal

I'm using the *[UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/)* plug-in.  I'd like to make *[SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)* block out only the "center pane" instead of the entire body of the document. I mention this because I haven't tried it in a document not having *UI Layout*, and am not sure if it is a factor.

Is this possible with *SimpleModal*? Is the `appendTo` option supposed to allow this? (I have tried it, it doesn't seem to be the intention of the option).

Would I have to manipulate the overlay and the dialog position in the `onOpen` callback? If this is not currently supported, it sounds like a useful option to have.

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

the `appendTo` option was added to support .NET forms and would not help in this case. I'm not a big fan of answering a question with "have you tried something else", but have you tried [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)?

Comment: hmm... would it be possible to use "Block UI" with "simplemodal"? The "BlockUI" page recommends using "jqModal" ("For full-featured modal dialog support, check out the jqModal Plugin by Brice Burgess.") I did try "jqModal" also, but as far as I can tell it also does not support blocking of div's instead of body. I guess I could still do the dialog form with "block UI" - except that there's a bunch of stuff I'd then need to do manually.

Would there be any chance that simplemodal could have this functionality added (for non-.net uses)? Is this possible?

Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: Yes, you can use them both together. Given my current time constraints, I don't see me having the time to add that feature any time soon. And I'll have to talk to Mike about suggesting jqModal ;)